# Git vs. Portable git

Tags: git, portable-apps

I don't do my system reinstalls that often, and the last time I looked there was only "regular" git on the [download list](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list). Now I see they pushed out the portable variant as well ... only I haven't been able to find what exactly do they entail by "portable" ... since git needs enviromental variables & stuff. to work properly ...

Could anyone give a short explanation in a word or two? (well, ... ten to twenty :-)

*I know I could just install it, and then remove it - but I prefer to avoid doing just that on a new system.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Portable, in this context, means that you don't need any special installation procedure. You can just unpack the archive on a USB drive (typical case) and run it from there. The opposite of portable would be a program that needs some files to be at a specific location in the filesystem hierarchy, that requires registry entries, etc.

By the way, all git needs is a place to store checkouts and repositories. Environment variables automate some tasks, but they're not required for basic operation, you can use command line arguments instead, and you can set them for a single terminal session if you want to use them. So they don't affect portability.

Comment: So basically, it is self contained, doesn't store reg. entries, and if I use the portable variant I'll need to supply command line arguments to commands. Otherwise from that, things are like usual (i.e. everything related to project goes to .git).

Comment: To be specific, everything about a repo is contained in a `.git` directory. @Rook.

Comment: That's not the whole definition, though. Portable apps also usually don't leave traces on the host system. They shouldn't write config files on them or (on windows) should not add registry entries. In this particular case it would be interesting how portable git stores credentials? (Assuming someone uses HTTPS Authentication)